# PHPMyAdmin Won't Stay Logged In

Tags: phpmyadmin

Just installed WAMP Server 3 (the version that has PHP 7) on a 64bit windows 7 machine and everytime I try to do anything with PHPMyAdmin (even clicking the logo to goto the main menu) i get logged out.

I've tried disabling the token check but that didn't work. What could be causing PHPMyAdmin sessions to expire the instant that they're created?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't modify the value of `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']` to some obscenely low value like 2, the most likely cause is a problem with the session folder on your webserver.

Look at the phpinfo output (which you can get most easily by creating a new file in your web root (called info.php or whatever you prefer) with the content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and find the directive `session.save_path`. Check that folder, make sure that it exists, is writable by the webserver process, and has enough disk space.

Comment: I uninstalled WAMP then re-installed it and disabling the token check has now worked, just need to work out why it's stopped working

Comment: Did you check the `session.save_path`? Also, you could look in the webserver error log for any hints about what might be going on, there's a chance something's getting logged there.